# division of binary numbers with zeros

Tags: math, binary, division

Well, me again.

Im struggling with division of binary numbers.

Well I try to understand following odd calculation:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualsystem#Schriftliche_Division

if the results got not zeros in it, I understand how it works.

I just dont undestand how to handle it if the divisor is bigger than the divident, so you have to write zeros in the result but there is no need to subtract... I just dont know what to do :(. Can someone explain me this question?

THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are in this situation:

```
   1000010 ÷ 11 = 01
 − 011
 —————
   0010
```

Binary 10 is smaller than binary 11, so you have to write down a 0 for the result. Furthermore, you copy one more digit from the original divident to the number below the line. So after this steps, you arrive at

```
   1000010 ÷ 11 = 010
 − 011 |
 ————— V
   00100
```

That's all. If there are no more digits to copy, you are left with a reminder for your division operation. Depending on context, you might want to remember that, ignore it or use it for rounding.

Comment: okay what i really dont undestand: 10000 - 011 (aligned) results in 00100... WTF happened? I took: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/Division/ShiftSubtract/Shift.Subtract.html 10000/11 ...

Comment: hm okay i probably forgot the 2 complement addition